# Stack resizable and fixed-size JLabels along each other on a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, layout

I am trying to fashion a custom-looking status-bar for a Swing desktop GUI. This status bar should have a resizable "field" attached to the left/west edge, with a number of fixed-size "fields" stacked to its right (or attached to the right/east edge).

A simple illustration (VS = variable size, FS = fixed size)

Initial size:

[image]

And after resize:

[image]

My approach so far is to position a `JPanel` at the bottom of my `JFrame` using a standard `LayoutManager` (which will depend on what I will have in the "body" of my frame). This `JPanel` will serve as the statusbar container. I am trying to figure out how to add/position some `JLabel`s inside the statusbar panel as I illustrated above. I am not sure how to go about this using standard LayoutManagers.

Can this be done or does it need a custom `LayoutManager`, and how?

Comment: GridBagLayout using appropriate weightx grid bag constraints could handle this. Also, BoxLayout.

Comment: I might consider looking at mig layout or possibly writing my own ... but I'm crazy 

Comment: If you need fixed and dynamic sizes, you can use [FormLayout](https://www.formdev.com/jformdesigner/doc/layouts/formlayout/).

Comment: `SpringLayout` should be a candidate also.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I'll explore my options.
@MadProgrammer It will be truly mad to write a custom layout for such a trivial task ;p

Comment: @SergiyMedvynskyy Any examples on how to use FormLayout to accomplish my task? Any special considerations for using FormLayout from NetBeans?

Comment: GridBagLayout would probably be the easiest. Just set the `weightx` constraint to 1 for the first component and 0 for all others. Or you could use the BoxLayout. The trick here would be to set the maximum size of the fixed fields to be the preferred size. The variable field would have an unlimited maximum size. Or you could nest panels. Have the fixed components added to a panel using a FlowLayout. Then use a second panel with a BorderLayout. The variable component can be added to the CENTER and the panel to the LINE_END.

Comment: *It will be truly mad to write a custom layout for such a trivial task* - read the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) to learn the basics, Then you choose the approach you want to use.

Comment: @SergiyMedvynskyy As you appear to be finding, this is not the "simple" task you seem to think it to be, a custom layout would allow you to better define and control the rules around which the components are laid out - it shouldn't be your first option, but it might be a better long term option